# is there an idiomatic way to make a retry loop in F#

Tags: f#

I have code that does the following:

```
// pseudo code
let maxRetry = 10
let mutable tryCount = 0
let mutable myResult: Result option = None
while tryCount < maxRetry do

    let result = try something
    if result = success then
        myResult <- some result
        tryCount <- maxRetry
    else
        some delay

myResult
```

The lack of a return function in F# makes this code quite bloated. Is there a more concise and idiomatic way to interrupt loops and return a result in F#? everything I have found so far is quite similar to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not defining what you mean by "bloated". What is it you're after? Fewer variables? Fewer lines of code? Something else?

The usual way of writing loops in functional programming is via recursion:

```
let rec loop retries =
    let result = try something
    if result = success then
        Some result
    elif retires <= 0 then
        None
    else
        some delay
        loop (retries - 1)

loop 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have function that returns true when passed 3 by.  You can break the loop using Seq.skipWhile.  It will execute f only 3 times not 10.  Finally, it will return Some(true) since it succeded.

```
let f n = n=3

[1..10]
|> Seq.map f
|> Seq.skipWhile not
|> Seq.tryHead
```

if you define

```
let f n = n= 11
```

It will only execute f 10 times and return None.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically there should be no (additional) mutable state.

The explicit route is to do it in a recursive function, something like;

```
let rec trySomethingNTimes =
    function 
    | 0 -> None
    | n ->
        match trySomething () with
        | result when result = success -> Some result
        | _ -> trySomethingNTimes (n - 1)
```

You could probably do it with a seq.unfold and a seq.last...but that may be more convoluted